# How can I discuss my suspension with the site's moderators?

Tags: support, moderators, account-suspension, moderator-messages

I recently got a hefty 30 day suspension handed to me over at [Programming Puzzles and Code Golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com) and, wanting to discuss the particulars, I replied to the email the moderator team sent me, requesting a chance to discuss the suspension with them. That was 6 days ago. I haven't yet had a reply.

I would ping one of the mods in chat, like I would normally, but, as a suspended user, I can't use chat. I also can't flag, or alert them in any way over on that site, and it wouldn't be acceptable to alert them on a different site. And to top it all off, I can't send another mod message to them until they reply to me previous one.

Therefore, I am looking for some way to alert the site mods, and would be grateful if anyone could either help me, or even point those mods in the direction of the post.

I am aware that this may get closed as "too specific" but for those close <s>vultures</s> votes, think of this: change the site, and this could apply to any of the many SE sites and I have no other way of making this issue known.

Comment: 30 days are rarely a first suspension - but yeaaaah, as a mod, under these specific set of circumstances. this is probably the best venue for the question in general. If nothing else, someone will likely ping a passing mod about the specific issue.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You say that you "have no other way of making this issue known", but I would expect that you still have access to the [Contact Us](https://meta.stackexchange.com/contact) button at the bottom of every page.

This will enable you to contact Stack Exchange staff who have access to all details of your suspension and lead up, that users of this site will not.  They will be able to contact your site's moderators and ask them to send a responding mod message, if they think that is warranted.

Once you have received a message from the moderators of a site, especially if it is accompanied by a suspension, it is very important that you use that opportunity to respond wisely, because there is only one such opportunity per mod message.

Answer (score 12):

Make sure before you contact them you understand exactly what the voting irregularity message means: https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/199772/2915 Hopefully after reading that you have a better idea of what might have triggered it and can discuss the issue in more detail.

Given that the 30 day suspension isn't handed out to first time offenders, you might instead direct your comments to Stack Exchange, Inc using the "contact us" option in the bottom menu.

You might also consider looking at your own account for clues.  For instance, your profile has the following text:

> I like listing things. Here is a list.
>
> - user66833
> - Valyrio Account
> - wsbltc
> - Soyoucanreplytomeincomments
> - This Guy
> - user00001
> - Satans Son
> - Random User
> - I like my dog
> - caird coinheringaahing

Further investigation shows some of these are accounts recently deleted from that site, and one now deleted meta question has the google snippet:

> Are you over 10k rep? - Programming Puzzles & Code Golf Meta Stack ...
>   https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/12081/are-you-over-10k-rep
>   Apr 12, 2017 - After all, @ThisGuy is at least your 3rd user name after user66833 and valyrio-account. Theoretically I have nothing against using my username ...

So I'm not sure what about your situation leaves you confused about your suspension.  You've been suspended before.  You have multiple accounts. The suspension is specifically due to voting irregularities.

If you feel that absolutely no voting irregularities have occurred in regards to your multiple sock puppet accounts then it's no longer a problem for moderators to solve, you'll need to check in with Stack Exchange customer service, have them investigate, and if you are correct they will work with the moderators to resolve the suspension.

Other possible considerations:

[Rule violations?](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/966/rule-violations/968)

[Multiple Accounts](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/12005/multiple-accounts)

Comment: I am aware what caused my suspension, however I would still like to discuss certain parts of that suspension with the moderators. This doesn't really answer the actual question, rather it tells me why you think I've been suspended. -1

Comment: @cairdcoinheringaahing I see what you mean.  In that case this really is a duplicate of https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/257611/cannot-send-a-message-to-moderator - you've sent the message, they have chosen not to respond, you cannot send a second message, and your only recourse is through Stack Exchange customer service. Good luck!

Comment: Also, slight nitpick: I *had* multiple accounts. After all, this is my *second* suspension. And if you feel that it's a duplicate, please VTC. It tends to happen with my Meta.SE posts :(

Comment: @cairdcoinheringaahing However, since the questions I linked don't answer the specific questions you have for the moderators, why not create a new question here that would help flesh out specific suspension reasons? It might help others avoid the situation you are in.

Comment: because, despite being fairly open with the suspension details, there are some thing regarding it that I don't want the Internet seeing.

Comment: @cairdcoinheringaahing When I have code I can't share, but it demonstrates a bug, I usually rewrite the code so it doesn't share sensitive information but still showcases the bug.  What you're saying is that the detail you have a question about cannot be framed in a way that doesn't reveal sensitive information?  If so, I'm sorry to hear that, I'm sure it would be of benefit to others, but of course you have to gauge the risk/reward yourself.  Hopefully you you find resolution!